# Google Chrome console auto scrolls when I click on an object

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, console

There are several different questions about this. However, I still have not been able to solve the problem.

When I am debugging in Google Chrome's console, I do want to see the content of objects

i.e

```
{a:'a'}
```

So I click on them to expand them. Many times (randomly), I get auto scrolled to the bottom of the console, getting me in really hard troubles to debug the object I am trying to watch.

I've read about bug with zooming in and out. But that did not help at all.
I have last google chrome version, checked with other workmates, and they do not have this problem.

What can it be? How can I fix it?

Since it happens randomly, I can not think it's a feature.

I have tried to reinstall chrome several times, did not help at all. Also sent them a report, but never received an answer.

Comment: I keep having the same issue, across versions. I'm presently on 59. FML this kills productivity and increases rage levels.

Comment: Also running into this issue on all versions of chrome including 56 and 60! Makes me want to hit people... especially if the object is at the top of the list

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version you were having issues with, but I just upgraded from chrome 56 to 57 and that fixed this issue for me.